# Overwrite div text to 0 or 1 depend on the div text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<td>
  <div class="status">10</div>
  <span class="fa fa-times-circle"></span>
</td>
```

And I have the script below to overwrite the 'status' class to 1 if its text is <30 and 0 if >30. In the above case the class status is 10, so I need it to overwrite and indicate 1. The script that I have doesn't do that. Can anyone help?

```
$.each($('tr .status'), function(i, v) {
    var $this = $(this).text();
  if($this > 0) {
    ($this < 30) ? $(this).text('1') : $(this).text('0');
  }
});
```

Comment: Change `.text` to `.html`. And Change `$.each` to `$('tr .status').each(function(i, v))`

Comment: Can you supply all of your code @MasterJoe

Comment: Please edit and refine your question like sample of wanted HTML. After on you jquery snippet, your are indicated the <tr> but it is not present in our sample fragment so mostly your sample fragment is incomplete.

Comment: It works. Thanks.

Comment: @HarshitJain: The OP's code works without either of those changes. The first is probably a bad idea, the second is style.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.each($('.status'), function(i, v) {
  var $this =parseInt( $(this).text());
  if ($this > 0) {
    ($this < 30) ? $(this).text('1'): $(this).text('0');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status">10</div>
<span class="fa fa-times-circle"></span>
```

1. Parse the text to compare

Comment: *"Parse the text to compare"* `>` and `<` will both coerce strings to numbers when comparing to a number (such as `> 0` or `< 30`). The OP's code works just fine (though it's certainly not how I would have written it).

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing text against numbers, that's gonna give some funky output. Try to do the following:

```
$.each($('tr .status'), function(i, v) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var value =  Number($this.text());
  if(value > 0 && !== isNaN(value)) {
    (value < 30) ? $this.text('1') : $this.text('0');
  }
});
```

In that way you force the value to a number.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're using `tr .status` but in your HTML its a DIV, so it should be `div.status`, also you should use `parseInt()` because `$(this).text()` will give you a string, not an integer.

https://jsfiddle.net/sbyc4mfp/

Comment: It's `tr<space>.status` so is fine, it's not `tr.status`

Answer (score -1):

Just have a look at this piece of JavaScript:

```
$('tr .status')
```

This cascade does not fit your HTML code.
Change the cascade to

```
 $('td .status')
```

or change the td-tag to an tr-tag in the HTML.

Comment: Why do you think `tr .status` doesn't work?   it's not `tr > .status`

Comment: Change the `td` to `tr`??  Really?  That's not how HTML works.